# Adjective for the discussion that goes by the same track again and again

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Adjective for the discussion that goes on through the same points over and over again.

Example:

> Okay, I think we should end this discussion, it starts to become ________.

Comment: I'm reminded of the Daffy Duck and Bugs Bunny discussion about what hunting season it is... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:WABBITSEASON&redirect=no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discussion that goes  on through the same points over and over is  ***[repetitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repetitive)***  :

​

> involving doing or saying the same thing several times, especially in a way that is boring:

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 4):

> Okay, I think we should end this discussion, *we’re just going round in circles*.

[Go round in circles](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-round-in-circles-go-around-in-circles) is a commonly used colloquialism for a discussion or debate that keeps coming back to the same points.

> If you say that someone is going round in circles or around in circles, you mean that they are not achieving anything because they keep coming back to the same point or problem.

Comment: The discussion itself can be described as circular

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think we should end this discussion, it starts to become **fruitless**.

> - useless; unproductive; without results or success:
>     a fruitless search for the missing treasure. [D.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fruitless)

**"unproductive"** also works well.

Or "repetitious"/"repetitive" if that's the case.

> [**repetitious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repetitious) - characterized or marked by repetition

Comment: First time I see repetitious, it looks uncommon though. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repetitive%2C+repetitious&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepetitive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepetitious%3B%2Cc0